# How to read a Jinja2 template and get a list of need variable to render it?

Tags: python, jinja2

I need to get the list of variable needed in the context of a template to be able to give some feedback to the programmer that will use [my service](http://github.com/novagile/diecutter).

How can I do that ?

I was thinking on giving a context object that will create the variable when the template try to access it and then give me the list of variable in the context object after rendering.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you supply a variable 'varnames' and communicate to the template designers that they can use it to look up the available variables.

Comment: Because I only have the template content to get this information.

Comment: You might have some luck monkeypatching the context object's 'resolve' method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parse the template and you can find all the variables : http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#the-meta-api
Example included.

Answer (score 7):

Use jinja2 [meta api](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#the-meta-api):

```py
from pathlib import Path
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader,meta

template_filename = "templates/foo.txt"  # Template path relative to my dir.
my_dir = Path(__file__).parent # Dir of the current file.
jenv = Environment(
    autoescape=False,
    loader=FileSystemLoader(my_dir),
    trim_blocks=False,
)
template_source =jenv.loader.get_source(jenv, template_filename)[0]
parsed_content = jenv.parse(template_source)
variables= meta.find_undeclared_variables(parsed_content)
print(variables)
```

output : Set of used variables

```
set(['CONFIG_PARAM_HTTPS_PROXY_PORT', 'CONFIG_PARAM_HTTP_PROXY_PORT'])
```